# Default value of minimum session duration

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In firebase, there is default event **session_start** which is automatically sent when a user engages the app for more than the minimum session duration.

What is minimum session duration if I don't change it? I can't find it anywhere in [docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is 10 seconds, you can see it in the [doc android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setMinimumSessionDuration(long)), [doc iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_analytics_configuration.html#a5c3d5801d596a25b4af6b9dd696918ab)

Quote of the android link (it is the same on iOS):

> Sets the minimum engagement time required before starting a session.
>   **The default value is 10000 (10 seconds)**.