# Firebase - best practice for session_start and user_engagement

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I just started to work with Firebase events.
And I see a lot of garbage in data:

1. I see "interactions" with `os_update` or `app_update` events with nothing more, so there is not actually a "session", but `session_start` is also sent.

Example:

```
app_update 12:00:01 
session_start 12:00:02 
session_start 13:00:05
```

So I can't count "clean" metrics, for example - average sessions per user per week, because there is such garbage.

2. There are also "sessions" with only `session_start` event.

So, what I'm thinking:

1. I can't find to set minimum session duration, `setMinimumSessionDuration()` method is obsolete.
2. If I find a way to set minimum duration to 5sec
   There will be strange behavior, for example:

---

```
screen_view 12:00:01
session_start 12:00:04
```

It's strange that session start is after event and will be a loss of data, if user quit before session_start but have `screen_view`.
Maybe it's okay to cut the garbage.

3. If we set minimum duration to 5sec, to obviously we need to set minimum duration for firing `user_engagement` event, because it will be very strange to see `user_engagement` before session_start ot without session_start. So I think we should set minimum duration for user engagement like 10sec or 30sec.

So, how did you solved this problems?
Any tips and tricks, what is the best practice?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the default value is 10 seconds already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769549/default-value-of-minimum-session-duration?rq=1

Comment: nope, it's obsolete, now it's 0

Answer (score 0):

As @mr.frog correctly mentioned, the `setMinimumSessionDuration()` method is deprecated.

The current method to control the duration is the [`setSessionTimeoutDuration`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setSessionTimeoutDuration(long)).

It doesn't look like there is a best practice or recommendations from Firebase when it comes the minimum session duration.

Comment: nope, Farid mentioned different function, not relevant - that one set time for termination of session, not for start